# how can i run my XML file on android emulator

Tags: android

hi i have choose XML code over java code for static PNG images to display in android.Now i want to see my PNG file on android emulator but it is not showing anything.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you are doing then we can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setContentView(R.layout.foo);` where foo is the name of your XML.