# How to run layout xml in emulator in android studio

Tags: android, xml

I am new to XML and Android Studio. I was making an app in XML and wanted to run it in an emulator to see how it looked. But I am unable to do so.

[image: XML]

Is there any option to run it in an emulator?

whenever I try to run the build it shows nothing. I read the post (mentioned below) in Stack-Overflow and its already applied. Then also my app is not starting in the emulator.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9093744/how-can-i-run-my-xml-file-on-android-emulator]

Any Solutions?

Comment: `was making an app in XML ` Impossible. You could use Java or Kotlin or other. But not xml. Better tell what you are up to.

Comment: `read the post (mentioned below) ` Please post the url in such a way that we get a link.

Comment: The XML file you have is only the layout that has no functionality at all. To run it simply compile the complete app and run it i the emulator.

Comment: The emulator was bugged after restarting it worked thanks